# UI-bootstrap - Add a tab and select it by default

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a tab system using ui-bootstrap.

It's nearly fine but I'm still having trouble with the last tab when I add one.
Adding one tab is OK, but if I want to select it automatically once it's created, I've got a weird behaviour :
One tab added : fine
One tab added : not selected
One tab added : fine
One tab added : not selected
and so on ...

I've made a **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/18ZLXFeUJlH2EuOy9FI7?p=preview)** to demonstrate my bug, just click multiple times on the "+" button and have a look to which tab is selected.

Here's the JS code :

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.tabs = [{
    title: 'Dynamic Title 1',
    content: 'Dynamic content 1',
    active: false
  }, {
    title: 'Dynamic Title 2',
    content: 'Dynamic content 2',
    active: false
  }];

  $scope.addTab = function() {
    $scope.tabs.push({
      title: 'Dynamic Title ' + ($scope.tabs.length + 1),
      content: 'Dynamic content ' + ($scope.tabs.length + 1)
    });

    $scope.active = $scope.tabs.length - 1;
  };

});
```

Here's the HTML code :

```
  <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <p>Select a tab by setting active binding to true:</p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 1">Select second tab</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 2">Select third tab</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[1].disabled = ! tabs[1].disabled">Enable / Disable third tab</button>
    </p>
    <hr />

    <uib-tabset active="active">
      <uib-tab index="$index" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
        {{tab.content}}
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>

    <br /><br />

    <button ng-click="addTab()">plus</button>

  </div>
```

Any help on this would be nice,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a timeout, uibootstrap doesn't technically support dynamically generated tabs.

```
$timeout(function() {
   $scope.active = $scope.tabs.length - 1;
}, 0);
```

See this thread.
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5656

Comment: So there's no API, nothing to inject in my controller to handle this ? It's weird...

Comment: What do you mean by no API ?

Comment: Not from what I can see.
It's a shame would be useful in what I'm building currently.
Timeout trick does work though.
And there's literally no bad side to using it except people who will judge you for using a timeout!
I'm not one of them.

Comment: Sampath thank you for your answer, I'll accept it even if I expected way more from a library used by people from angular and bootstrap !

@CHAZTATS I agree that it's a shame but the timeout tricks works ...
I don't care about people judging me, but I do care about making clean code so I'm still very disappointed by that.